# QGIS Map Composers missing

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am working with a project that resulted in the composition of five(5) Map composers, then suddenly when I transfer my whole project in a different computer all the Map Composers made was lost. what went wrong?  and how can I retrieve those missing map composers ?

Comment: What versions of QGIS on the two computers?

Comment: they are both Qgis 2.18.

Comment: Do you still have access to the original project file? If so, I recommend trying the transfer again.